# Firebase .value observer not listening if ref does not exist, but later exists

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Suppose users have a node where the ids of all their favourited posts are stored (/users/$uid/favourites/$postid). So, in my ViewController, I observe the /users/$uid/favourites/ node so I can get all the favourite postids, and then iteratively fetch the post objects.

If the user has no favourites, then the 'favourites' node does not yet exist. I find that if I attach a .value event observer in this state, it never fires when the user later favourites a post (that is, when the 'favourites' ref becomes existent. This issue does not happen if I use a .childAdded observer.

Is this a bug or a specific design feature? Also, is there a workaround...of course, one not requiring me to use a .childAdded observer. Thanks.

Comment: Firebase value observers fire immediately with the current value at the location. If there is no value, they immediately fire with an empty snapshot. If that is not the case for you, share the [minimal code that reproduces the behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Frank, I resolved the issue, it was a side-effect of some weird security rule that was preventing observation of the node. I've spent a lot of time fighting this issue on the client-side and didn't even think about this. To show "minimal code that reproduces the behavior", I spinned off a clean firebase project with the bare minimum node structure and the issue did not occur. Then 'diffed' the two projects and discovered the only difference was the security rules. I changed the rules on my current project and now .value event listening now works as expected.

Comment: See.... creating an MCVE often helps you find your own problem. Good work!

Answer (score 0):

It should work as you have described. Make sure that when you add the `.value` event listener you are doing so inside a `.observe()` listener rather than a `observeSingleEvent()` listener.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but am already using a .observe, rather than a .observerSingleEvent

Comment: In that case, make sure you haven't got any typos in the code because above, `favouries` ≠ `favourites`.

Comment: The typo in my question was just a mistake as I was typing on my phone (autocorrect did its thing), my code however is typo-free and double-checked. Am surprised no one else has come across this issue. @Bradley, can you try reproducing this just like I have described? You might be surprised that it behaves just like I have explained.

Comment: I resolved the issue, please see my comment to Frank above. Thanks for all the help.